# List<T>.ForEach - Is the object passed into ForEach a reference or a copy?

Tags: c#

When using `List<T>.ForEach` is the object that's passing in i.e. the `j` in the example below passed by reference or by value?

```
MyList.ForEach( j => {} );
```

If I was to do something like:

```
MyList.ForEach( j => {
    j.someOtherList.Add("value");
});
```

Would this be acting on a copy of `j` or would it be acting on the original object?

Comment: Depends. Is `j` an instance of a reference or value type?

Comment: It's a `reference` but you can't assign that `reference` to another, however because it's `reference`, you can change/modify all the properties of your objects.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: It doesn't really depend: the value is passed *by value* either way... but that value may be a reference (never an object).

Comment: @Jon, yes, the value is passed by value even if the value is a reference :) When I posted my first comment, I was more focused on the possible differences between `j` being an instance of a value or reference type, especially if `someOtherList` was itself an instance of a reference type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There isn't an *object* passed in at all - there's a *value* of type `T`. If `T` is a reference type, that value is a reference. The value is passed *by* value, just as normal.

Now assuming `T` is some reference type with a member called `someOtherList`, then your code will indeed affect the *object* that the value of `j` refers to - but the value of `j` is just a reference. The value within the list will be the *same* reference, so you'll be able to see the effect if you then (say) iterate over the list again.

Importantly, if you changed your code to:

```
MyList.ForEach( j => {
    j = new WhateverYourTypeIs()
});
```

that would *not* affect the list at all.

I suspect you may have a little confusion about how pass-by-value and pass-by-reference work, particularly in the context of C#. I have an [article on the topic](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html) which may help you.

Comment: Sorry, my terminology was incorrect. But thank you for clearing this up Jon. Makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

This is a kind of comment (too long to fit in the comment field).

Jon Skeet already gave the answer: It is passed "normally", i.e. passed by value, where the *value* is the entire object itself for a value type, while the *value* is a reference to the object's "location" for a reference type. So the example in the question is likely to "work" (assuming that `someOtherList` is a reference type member of the type of `j`).

But just for the fun of it, I wrote an alternative `ForEachByRef` where it is by-ref:

```
public delegate void ActionByRef<J>(ref J j);

public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static void ForEachByRef<T>(this List<T> list, ActionByRef<T> action)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; ++i)
        {
            T t = list[i];
            action(ref t);
            list[i] = t;
        }
    }
}
```

Then this works:

```
static void Main()
{
    var testList = new List<string> { "alpha", "bravo", "charlie", };
    testList.ForEachByRef((ref string j) => { j = "changed"; });
}
```

(I don't recommend actually using a method like `ForEachByRef` in "real" code; this was just for the illustration.)

Comment: I really appreciate the effort put into the comment. It's a shame I can't accept two answers. Thank you.